# How does netstat find ESTABLISHED connections

Tags: ubuntu, networking, netstat

If I perform an operation that establishes a TCP connection (e.g., an HTTP connection), the first thing that happens is that the 3-step TCP handshake is made. If I then use `netstat`, it shows me that there is a TCP connection with state ESTABLISHED:

```
$ netstat -an | grep ESTAB
Proto   Recv-Q  Send-Q Local Address       Foreign Address         State
tcp          0       0 <source IP>:49472   <destination IP>:80     ESTABLISHED
```

1. How does `netstat` know that my client software made a TCP handshake with the server and that there now is an established connection?  My best guess is that `netstat` looks at file descriptors or something else in the OS that holds this information, but I can't find any information about it.
2. Can I somehow check the connections in the same way that `netstat` internally does?

Comment: `netstat` usage should probably be replaced with `ss`. Both of these commands read files like /proc/self/net/tcp to get the information you are after. This is documented in the proc(5) manual page.

Comment: 1. netstat is just formatting the data from `/proc/net/{tcp,udp,unix,..}`. 2. Of course you can, `netstat` is just a program, like any other. You may do the same things it does. There are even better interfaces than the `/proc/` files, like [sock_diag](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sock_diag.7.html). You should also take into account the network namespace(s) you have access to.

Comment: @icarus `ss` does not get its information from `/proc`, but via `sock_diag` netlink sockets.

Comment: Thank you. Now when I see how it seems to work, my question seems pretty basic. For tcp connects this information is read in /proc/net/tcp, where the 4th attribute from the left would be the state that I am looking for:

 sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode                                                     
   0: 3500005E:0025 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000   101        0 24150 1 ffff8700a6664bc0 100 0 0 10 0